# C beginner coder, program is outputting junk values

Tags: c

I'm new here and it seems this site is the best place for advice.
My program is supposed to read a string that is 30 characters long. Then the program should copy the characters from that string into a second character array in order,
but only if the character is a vowel (a, e, i, o, u).

I'm a bit overwhelmed at the moment by it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The program prints lines of random characters.
The line is 30 long, like I want, but the output is random garbage.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAXSIZE = 31;

int main()
{
    char stringtwo[31]; 
    int i;
    int hold;
    char string[31] = {'\0'};

    printf("Enter message, upto 30 characters!\n");
    fgets(string, MAXSIZE, stdin);

    for(i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++)
    {
        hold = (int) string[i];

        if(hold == 97 && hold == 101 && hold == 105 && hold == 111 && hold == 117)
        {
            strcpy(stringtwo, string);
        }
    }
    /* Test to see if any vowels */
    if(strcmp(string, stringtwo) == 0)
    {
        printf("Strings are the same. \n");
    }

    for(i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", stringtwo[i]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `string` length should be 32 to include the null to terminate the string.

Comment: `strcpy(stringtwo, string);` --> `stringtwo[i] = string[i];`

Comment: @LiranFunaro emmm....why?

Comment: `if(hold == 97 && hold == 101 && hold == 105 && hold == 111 && hold == 117)` is mathematically wrong.

Comment: @SouravGhosh He put null in the 31 place in the array where the last element is 30.

Comment: Wow! You guys are fast, `stringtwo[i] = string[i];` that makes sense. Why is that mathematically incorrect? @SouravGhosh

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** `gdb` to run your program step by step, query its state, and understand its behavior

Comment: @HARB_INGER because a number cannot be 97 **and** 101 at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(hold == 97 && hold == 101 && hold == 105 && hold == 111 && hold == 117)
{
    strcpy(stringtwo, string);

}
```

should be

```
size_t vowels = 0;
/* Loop ... */
if (hold == 'a' || hold == 'e' || hold == 'i' || hold == 'o' || hold == 'u')
{
    stringtwo[vowels] = string[i];
    vowels++;
}
/* End loop ... */
stringtwo[vowels] = '\0';
```

Notice OR instead of AND, and don't use magic numbers like `97`, instead use the ASCII representation.

Also, you don't need to iterate `MAXSIZE` times in the loop

```
fgets(string, MAXSIZE, stdin);

for(i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++)
```

should be

```
fgets(string, MAXSIZE, stdin);
size_t len = strlen(string);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

Now you can compare

```
if (vowels == len)
```

instead of

```
if(strcmp(string, stringtwo) == 0)
```

Comment: `strcpy()`? sure?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, nops ;)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, you guys are honestly the best! It means alot! I understand that trying to convert to ASCII was silly, I actually understand how to use char data types now :D